# Tipsi-Stripe creating a source from a token

Tags: react-native, stripe-payments

I am trying to use tipsi-stripe to create a source which I will send to my server. I get the token fine with following code but creating a source from the token 
throws an error

```
 try {
      this.setState({ loading: true, token: null })
        const token = await stripe.paymentRequestWithCardForm({
          // Only iOS support this options
          smsAutofillDisabled: true,
          requiredBillingAddressFields: 'full',
          prefilledInformation: {
            billingAddress: billingAddress,
          },
        })
        this.setState({ 'token': token })

     var strToken=this.state.token;
     console.log(strToken);
     const params = {
       type:'card',
      token:strToken
    }

    const source = await stripe.createSourceWithParams(params)
```

Error is as follows

```
[Error: The payment method `card` requires the parameter: card[number].]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're likely passing a `Token` object where a `Card` objects is expected. From the token, you can get the [card](https://stripe.com/docs/api/tokens/object#token_object-card) and pass it as `card` in `params`.

Comment: @taintedzodiac I already tried that as well. Send the card object or just the card id , both generate the same error.

Comment: @RehanFazal Did you figure this out? I'm getting the exact same issue.